# Applescript Display Dialog User Input

Tags: applescript, user-input

I'm running an applescript program where I am asking for the user to type in their name.  If the user clicks "OK", then the name gets stored to the variable I want.  However, if the user clicks "Cancel", then the program just quits.  How do I set this up to either hide the "Cancel" button, so it's not an option to click, or to set up a loop so that if cancel is clicked, it just continues to ask the user for his/her name until it's entered?

Thanks in advance.

```
display dialog "Please Enter Your Name." default answer " " with title "Enter Name"
```

Answer (score 2):

simple solution

```
display dialog "Please Enter Your Name." default answer " " with title "Enter Name" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you hide the cancel button is like this:

```
display dialog "Please Enter Your Name." default answer " " buttons {"ok"} with title "Enter Name"
set a to the text returned of the result
```

But if you wanted the repeat then use this (I have made it so they have to enter something too instead of just pressing ok to end it:

```
repeat
 display dialog "Please Enter Your Name." default answer "" buttons {"ok", "cancel"} default button 1 with title "Enter Name"
set a to the text returned of the result
if the button returned of a is "ok" then
    if the text returned of a ≠ "" then
        exit repeat
    end if
 end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got:

```
display dialog "Please Enter Your Name." default answer "" buttons {"Submit"} with title "Enter Name" default button 1
    if the button returned of the result is "Submit" then
        set yourVariable to text returned of the result
    end if
```